# Node.js - do I need to reinstall all the modules on the production server when deploying the Node.js app

Tags: node.js, production

I have developed my first Node.js pp. For now, it just sits on my laptop.

During development I had to install some modules:

```
npm install socket.io
npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha3
npm install iniparser
npm install js-yaml
npm install nodemailer
```

I have installed all of them "per-project", not globally.

The directory of my project looks like this (my code is all in push_server.js):

```
|
|--- push_server.js
|
|--- node_modules
     |--- iniparser
     |--- js-yaml
     |--- mysql
     |--- socket.io
     |--- nodemailer
```

Now I want to push this project to the production server.

My question is: can I upload the whole codebase (including installed modules) or should I upload just the code of my app and re-install the modules one-by-one on the server?

Note: my dev machine runs Ubuntu 10.04, the production server runs CentOS 5.3

I think all those modules are made up of js files only, therefore it should be allright.
However, is it possible that a module installed by npm compiles some code on the local machine, therefore that code is likely not to work on another machine. Also, how can I know whether a module does that?

Hope the question is not too silly - I have just started with Node.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try to use the latest versions of the required modules. Node.js is still very young and whenever a module is updated it often brings bugfixes, speed improvements, etc. I install modules locally, test my code on them and finally use them in production. When you install them with `npm install module --save` they are automatically added to your `package.json` file as `dependencies`.

Using `git` for version control and deployment I usually put the `node_modules` folder into my `.gitignore` file. It is therefore not uploaded to my server. On the server you just have to run `npm install` to install all your required modules, which is much faster than installing them one by one.

This workflow is also used by [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs).

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely copy `node_modules` if possible.

If you re-download them at the server, you run a risk of getting slightly different versions of the modules in use.  Even if you require a strict module version X, that module can again have wildcard dependencies to other modules Y Z.  This means that if Y is updated and you publish to the server, it will now run using different code for Y than what you used for your local testing and validation.

In some cases you may not even have a required module available at deployment time, because the author has decided to de-publish the package for whatever reason.

Comment: Those are very good points. But what if a module compile code during its installation - that code is not going to be portable? Is that possible? I guess some of them does.

Comment: @dan A very good observation.  Some modules to that.  I'm just used to doing development testing on the same platform as production.  In that case you have no choice but to re-install them on production, or introduce a test staging server with the same platform as the production server.

Comment: Yes, actually I do staging on the same architecture as production...but it is still a pain as I would like the dev machine to run any Linux distribution.
How can I tell if some module compiled any software? Unfortunately running "tree" on the "node_modules" directory, I can see some .c and .h files - not good, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it will cause issues.  I'd go with a build&test stage server for this, but it really depends on what stability requirements your system has.  If it's OK for it to fail sporadically, you don't need to bother much. :)